# could dynamic object instantiation + arbitrary cast in java could lead to an RCE?

Tags: penetration-test, java

I was pentesting for a bug bounty program, I can't say more because it has been corrected but undisclosed. I still wonder though, did the reporter get an RCE ?

A webservice waited for XML, I first tried to XXE, mess with business logic, nothing juicy there. Then an attribute caught my attention, unused in anything burp had been able to capture, I found it in the JavaScript.

```
<blaa fieldtype="java.lang.ProcessBuilder"/>
```

lead to that error (blaa being initially a string)

```
could not convert java.lang.ProcessBuilder into java.lang.string
```

I tried

```
<blaa fieldtype="java.lang.ProcessBuilder"><command>bla</command></blaa>
```

same error.
However:

```
<blaa fieldtype="java.lang.ProcessBuilder"><foo><foo></blaa>
```

gave

```
unknown field java.lang.ProcessBuilder.foo
```

So at this point, I'm able to instantiate any arbitrary object, set any public property, and order cast from anything to anything, I fuzzed for hours and found no way to call a method. Is there an RCE here? Or did they correct from a report saying "User input should not be used dynamically in code"?

Comment: This may interest you: https://github.com/frohoff/ysoserial

Answer (score 1):

The answer will greatly depend on what is in the classpath. However, I cannot see in you XML snippet where you would pass the command to execute in your example.

So without knowing more about the environment it is impossible to answer your question. However, it would be beneficial for you to check out some [java deserialization gadgets](https://github.com/frohoff/ysoserial).

If you haven't heard about java deserialiaztion vulnerability I recommend [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KSA7vUkXGSg) and [this](https://foxglovesecurity.com/2015/11/06/what-do-weblogic-websphere-jboss-jenkins-%20opennms-and-your-application-have-in-common-this-vulnerability/).

Comment: I can't execute a command, I fuzzed serialized objects with several serialization method, nothing.The set up: if a node has the `fieldtype` attribute, any class available can be instantiated.
I can set any public attribute of the class instantiated.


`<blaa fieldtype="java.lang.ProcessBuilder"><command>bla</command></blaa>`


It will then try to cast input into desired type, so if I do

`<blaa fieldtype="java.lang.ProcessBuilder"><command fieldtype="java.lang.string">bla</command></blaa>`


this error will pop: `"could not convert java.lang.string into java.lang.list"`